# Username and Password in C

Tags: c, passwords

so basically I want to create a program that asks for an username and a password in order to enter the actual program. I tried doing something like that but when I type the first username and password it doesn't let me go through. On the other hand when I type the second username and password it does work. Can someone explain me why?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #define MAX 100
    #define LEN 40

    int names(char listName[][LEN]);
    void pass(char listPass[][LEN]);

    int main()
    {
    char name[LEN];
    char password[LEN];
    char listName[MAX][LEN];
    char listPass[MAX][LEN];
    int i;

    names(listName);
    pass(listPass);


    printf("Enter username: ");
    scanf("%s", name);

    printf("Enter password: ");
    scanf("%s", password);

    for(i = 0; i< 2; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(listName[i], name) == 0 && strcmp(listPass[i], password) == 0)
        {
            printf("Access granted\n");
            break;
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("Access denied\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    getch();
    }

    int names(char listName[][LEN])
    {
        int i;
        strcpy(listName[i], "Vince");
        strcpy(listName[i], "Jeremy");
    }

    void pass(char listPass[][LEN])
    {
        int i;
        strcpy(listPass[i], "aBc2xyz8");
        strcpy(listPass[i], "fa7saC12");
    }
```

Comment: You should always know the value of all variables. What value does `i` have when you enter the functions `names()` and `pass()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile with warnings enabled and you'd see that the variable `i` is used uninitialized here:

```
int names(char listName[][LEN])
{
    int i;
    strcpy(listName[i], "Vince");
    strcpy(listName[i], "Jeremy");
}

void pass(char listPass[][LEN])
{
    int i;
    strcpy(listPass[i], "aBc2xyz8");
    strcpy(listPass[i], "fa7saC12");
}
```

What you have now is *undefined behaviour*, i.e. anything can happen. More likely you'd just get a random crash.

You meant `strcpy(listName[0], "Vince");`, `strcpy(listName[1], "Jeremy");`

---

However, what you'd *really* want to do is to define these variables *out of `main`, and initialize them there. Also, allow for varying length passwords and usernames by using an array of pointers to char. For example:

```
char *listName[MAX] = { "Vince", "Jeremy" };
char *listPass[MAX] = { "aBc2xyz8", "fa7saC12" };

int main(void) { ...
```

Or even better, use a structure for user data:

```
struct user_data {
    char *username, *password;
};

struct user_data users[MAX] = {
    { "Vince", "aBc2xyz8" },
    { "Jeremy", "fa7saC12" }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In names() and pass() you use i uninitialized, both strcpy operations are going to copy to the same array index.

Answer (score 0):

Following code is not what you intended:

```
int names(char listName[][LEN])
{
     int i;
     strcpy(listName[i], "Vince");
     strcpy(listName[i], "Jeremy");
}

void pass(char listPass[][LEN])
{
    int i;
    strcpy(listPass[i], "aBc2xyz8");
    strcpy(listPass[i], "fa7saC12");
}
```

You should initialize i and increment it between the statements, or simply use:

```
int names(char listName[][LEN])
{
    strcpy(listName[0], "Vince");
    strcpy(listName[1], "Jeremy");
}

void pass(char listPass[][LEN])
{
    strcpy(listPass[0], "aBc2xyz8");
    strcpy(listPass[1], "fa7saC12");
}
```